# How do I output what wget retrieves to stdout and suppress all other wget messaging?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget, stdout

I'm using bash shell on Amazon Linux.  I have a command in a shell script

```
wget -O - "http://localhost:8088/subco/books/$e_id/segments/$segment_id?product=$product_id&audience=teacher" > /dev/null
```

Reading this -- https://superuser.com/questions/321240/how-do-you-redirect-wget-to-standard-out/321241, I was led to believe I could output the result of wget (what it retrieves) to my screen and suppress all other output.  However instead, what I get is

```
--2018-05-29 18:39:49--  http://localhost:8088/subco/books/C2644BB08F394E209A26175BD2C89F5A/segments/C2F62E7002964DD396E381DB331129A4?product=D399B9C5F6204EDE80A002930CC0D02F&audience=teacher
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8088... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’
```

How do I output the result of wget to the screen and suppress all other information (e.g. like the "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK" part)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use wget, the use -qO -

```
wget -qO - google.com
```

Or you could use curl with no options

curl google.com

And if you want to go a little further and parse results etc, the package BeautifulSoup for Python is great.

Comment: thanks for the `curl` suggestion, it's the perfect tool for my use case.

Comment: what if you want to issue a POST request?